# Custom validation is not working while saving the form

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have created a custom form element (FileUpload). In this FileUpload I assigned some validation (content type, file size). If I enable the validation and push the apply button, the changes are gone after the submit.

How can we solve this kind of issue?

Before saving the form: [image]

After saving the form: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your model behind the control. Does it inherit Input to store the validators?

[image]

Your item should have a section to store the validation settings.

[image]